# javascript memory game, need to add congrats message at the end of game

Tags: javascript

I have created a memory game with javascript, html and css, the game is complete but I am having difficulty adding the last part, which that when all cards are matched a message box need to show to the user e.g. "Well Done! all cards have been matched". I tried SweetAlert and different lines of code, but can't get the message.

I am showing here the whole JS code here and HTML at the bottom of the page

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

//On first flipped card if match with second flipped card it will lock both cards
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();

}

//If cards match it will freeze those cards and it will prevent them from flipping back - managed with dataset html atribute
function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.legend === secondCard.dataset.legend;

  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

//Matched card will be disabled for clicks once they are flipped
function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

//If cards don't match it will flip the cards back in 0.5s and you will have a new attempt to make
function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 500);

  // Add Move
  addMove();

}

//Moves
const movesContainer = document.querySelector(".moves");
let moves = 0;
movesContainer.innerHTML = 0;
function addMove() {
    moves++;
    movesContainer.innerHTML = moves;

    rating();

}

//Star Rating
const starsContainer = document.querySelector(".stars");
const star = `<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>`;
starsContainer.innerHTML = star + star + star;
function rating() {

    if( moves < 12) {
        starsContainer.innerHTML = star + star + star;
    } else if( moves < 18) {
        starsContainer.innerHTML = star + star;
    } else {
        starsContainer.innerHTML = star;
    }
}


//Timer
const timerContainer = document.querySelector(".timer");
let liveTimer,
    totalSeconds = 0;

timerContainer.innerHTML = totalSeconds + ' s';

 function startTimer() {
    liveTimer = setInterval(function() {
        totalSeconds++;
        timerContainer.innerHTML = totalSeconds + 's';
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer()

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(liveTimer);
}


//Congrats message




//Game Reset
function myButton() {
  location.reload();
}

//If second card match with first card it will return from the function
function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
}

//Use to shuffle cards - 8 front and 8 back side = 16
(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });

})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Your Memory</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- info -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>Test Your Memory</h1>
    </div>

    <section class="score-panel">Rating:
    <ul class="stars"></ul>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
    Moves: <span class="moves"></span>
<hr>
<br>
    Timer: <span class="timer"></span>
<hr>
<br>
      <button onclick="myButton()">Start Over Again</button>

  </div>
  </section>
  <!-- end info -->

  <!-- game -->
  <section class="game">
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend1">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend1.png" alt="Github" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend1">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend1.png" alt="Github" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend2">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend2.png" alt="Tumblr" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend2">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend2.png" alt="Tumblr" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend3">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend3.png" alt="Wikipedia" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend3">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend3.png" alt="Wikipedia" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend4">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend4.png" alt="Tumblr" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend4">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend4.png" alt="Tumblr" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend5">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend5.png" alt="Wordpress" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend5">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend5.png" alt="Wordpress" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend6">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend6.png" alt="Wikipedia" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend6">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend6.png" alt="Wikipedia" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend7">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend7.png" alt="The New York Times" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend7">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend7.png" alt="The New York Times" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-legend="legend8">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend8.png" alt="Wordpress" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-legend="legend8">
      <img class="front" src="images/legend8.png" alt="Wordpress" />
      <img class="back"/>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- end game -->

<script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML too.

Comment: @AndrewL I have posted html just now. Thank you

Comment: Have you already implemented the code that checks if matches are all done? have you tried using window.alert?

Comment: @SomoKRoceS I didn't do that. Can you help me with writing that please?

Comment: @Jomla look at my answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54174537/5750016), let me know if you need more clarifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your code right, then when there is a match of two cards - 'resetBoard' is called.
In that case i would set up a counter, initialized to zero, that incremented every 'resetBoard' call.

So, at the top of your script i would add:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

//On first flipped card if match with second flipped card it will lock both cards
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let matchCounter=0;
.
.
.
```

Then, when there is a match.. we will increment that variable:

```
.
.
.
//If second card match with first card it will return from the function
function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
  matchCounter+=1;
}
.
.
.
```

Now, I am not sure if there is a function that checks if the game is over (tell me if i missed that one), but lets assume there isn't. In that case we can add an if statement that checks if the player matched all cards (which means that the matchCounter should equals the amount of pairs):

```
.
.
.
//If second card match with first card it will return from the function
function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
  matchCounter+=1;
  if(matchCounter==(cards.length/2)){
      window.alert("Congratulations! You Won!");
  }
}
.
.
.
```

window.alert simply pops up a message in browser.

**EDIT:**

Ok, after another look at your code I found that resetBoard() is called even there is not a match, so the increment and the if statement should be somewhere else, where you check if there was a match:

```
//If cards match it will freeze those cards and it will prevent them 
from flipping back - managed with dataset html atribute
function checkForMatch() {
 let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.legend === secondCard.dataset.legend;

if(isMatch){
    matchCounter+=1;
   disableCards();
     if(matchCounter==(cards.length/2)){
          window.alert("Congratulations! You Won!");
      }
   }
   else{ unflipCards(); }
}
```

Comment: yes you got it right, there is no function that checks if the game is over. What you did here look great but it gives me pop up message after only few matches and sometimes never pop up after matching all cards. I implement the code on the way how you have done it. Could you please check again if possible. Thank you

Comment: Hi, after another look at the code, I've edited my answer. Look at the edit. please do not alter resetBoard() and alter checkForMatch() instead.

Comment: you helped me so much. It’s working this way I really appreciate. Thank you